# Цикл неверно считает количество его проходов.

Tags: c

Здравствуйте!

При работе с файлом, требуется вывести все строчки на экран и посчитать их количество.
Но количество считается не верно, в чём просчёт?

```
    //Работа с файлами

#include<stdio.h>

main(void){

char resultfile[10000];

 int i = 0;

FILE *wf;
wf = fopen("WorkWithFile.txt", "r");

do{
fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile);
printf("In File: %s\n",resultfile);
i++; //тут считаем сколько строк
}
while( (fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile)) != EOF);

printf("Domain: %d\n", i);

fclose(wf);

    system("pause");
}
```

*Дополнение:*

Если писать так:

```
while( (fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile)) != EOF)
{
fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile);
printf("In File: %s\n",resultfile);
i++; /*А если добавить ещё одну i++; такую штуку, то считает верно.*/
}
```

То количество строк в 2 раза меньше от реального.

**Верный цикл, который правильно работает:**

```
while( (fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile)) != EOF)
{
printf("In File: %s\n",resultfile);
i++;
}
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну первое скорее всего на 1 единицу больше считает, я предполагаю.

```
do{}while
```

т.е. сначала выполняется, а потом проверяется условие.

если сделать while do то счетчик отработает корректно.

мне так кажется

**//upd**

зачем в цикле повторно делать fscan?

```
while( (fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile)) != EOF)  // пока fscan != EOF
        {  
         fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile);  и опять вызываешь её
```

> Сейчас попробую, но строчек выводится
> 321, а в количество он пишет 161

Строчки он выведет может и 321 но вглядись, скорее всего они поочередно идут одинаковые :)

Comment: Сейчас попробую, но точек выводится 321, а в количество он пишет 161.

Comment: Попробовал так:
 while( (fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile)) != EOF)
 {
 fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile);
 printf("In File: %s\n",resultfile);
 i++;
 }

Пишет ровно в 2 раза меньше от количества.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: @Shrek, где он делается повторно, не пойму?

Comment: Еще раз обновил. Ты понимаешь как вообще работает конструкция

while( (fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile)) != EOF) 
{}

Comment: @Shrek, Понял, благодарю!  
Я не знал что оно зачитывается, использовал его для проверки конца файла.

Верный вариант:

 while( (fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile)) != EOF)
 {
 printf("In File: %s\n",resultfile);
 i++;
 }

Answer (score 4):

А почему используется fscanf? Она же считывает не целые строки, а слова, т.е. набор символов между символами разделения: пробелами, табуляциями, концами строк и т.п. Если будет в середине строки пробел, то получите неправильный результат.

Надо использовать функцию  fgets. Она считывает из файлового потока строчку целиком. Например, так:

```
while (fgets (wf, 9999, resultfile)) {
   printf ("%s", resultfile);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: У меня есть большой список доменов(по 80-90к), мне не нужны знаки табуляции и т.п.  
Там на каждой новой строчке 1 домен, поэтому использую fscanf.  
Верно я рассуждаю?

Comment: fgets работает быстрее, чем fscanf.  Если у Вас такие большие файлы, это может оказаться существенным.

Comment: Но тогда придётся убирать лишнии символы из считываемой строки, или нет?

Comment: Если они там присутствуют, то придется. К тому, fgets оставляет символ окончания строки. Но это не проблема.

Comment: Вообще, пишите про задачу более конкретно: что считывается, что нужно получить и т.д.

Comment: Ну так это время занимает.  
А вообще, это не очень то и важно, так как после считывания домена будут делаться запросы к сайтам, что бы узнать какую-то информацию, а вот это очень сильно замедляет работу.   
Я сейчас пишу саму программу, а потом уже буду реализовывать многопоточность и оптимизировать её.

Answer (score 1):

Вы 2 раза вызываете fscanf() - 1 раз внутри оператора while(), второй раз в самом цикле, а инкрементируете счетчик 1 раз, поэтому количество строк в 2 раза меньше. Вам стоит использовать :

```
res = fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile);  
while( res != EOF);  
{  
    res = fscanf(wf, "%s", resultfile);  
    printf("In File: %s\n",resultfile);  
    i++;  
}
```

*Вариант avp получше будет, только я бы поставила условия "fscanf() > 0"*

Comment: @margosh, Спасибо!  
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант более правильный, который я написал уже в конце или ваш?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК,пока набирала ответ, Shrek уже Вам все обьяснил... варианты вобщем-то идентичны, если не к чему лишняя переменная res, то Ваш наверно даже более приемлим, но мой, IMXO, проще читается начинающими.

Comment: Зачем проверять конец файла в конце итерации цикла? Если файл пуст, то в Вашем варианте переменная i станет равной 1 и мы получим неправильный ответ. Поэтому ставлю минус.

Comment: @mikillskegg, Вы правы, слона не заметила, исправлю :)

Comment: Опять неправильно

Comment: Что на этот раз не так ?

Comment: А что содержится в переменной res до начала цикла? Положим, что EOF. Тогда сами понимаете, что будет. Если что-то другое, то опять будет ошибка: i будет в конце на 1 больше, чем число строк в файле.

Comment: ну я вообще-то и не собиралась всю функцию целиком писать, про res догадаться вроде можно, главное не забыть, что в разных ОС "EOF" может иметь различные значения.

Comment: Почему бы не написать просто ?

    for (i = 0; fscanf(wf,"%s",resultfile) == 1; i++) 
        printf("In File: %s\n",resultfile);

в конце **i** количество прочитанных слов (в Вашем случае строк).

Comment: > i будет в конце на 1 больше, чем число строк в файле.

Соглашусь. Действительно, в случае файла нулевого размера будет косяк. Да и вообще скорее всего тоже

Comment: @avp, тоже решение.